# playframework database connection set default and development database

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Hi in my playframework application I want to configure several database servers. I want one default for deployment. And a second one for development.

At the moment I have only one defined like this:

```
slick {
  dbs {
    default {
      profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
      db {
        driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url = ""
        user = ""
        password = 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

how can I add a second one ... Maybe like this:

```
slick {
  dbs {
    default {
      profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
      db {
        driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url = ""
        user = ""
        password = 
      }
    },
    development {
      profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
      db {
        driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url = ""
        user = ""
        password = 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is that correct? And how can I manage in which case I use the default and when the dev database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have multiple databases in one environment (like in prod) or you want to use one for local and one for production?

Comment: I want to use one for local development and one for production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application needs only one database - and you want to use one for local development and one for production (obviously), then you are only talking about one database. And the way you configure them is by using two different `conf` files like for local you use `application.conf` and for prod you use `prod-env.conf` and while you start the server in prod, you pass the `prod-env.conf` as a parameter to use.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Deploying#Using-the-dist-task

If you have multiple databases in one environment (like, if you have to deal with two different databases in your local (or prod)) - then you need to use `NamedDatabase("dbName")` injection as mentioned [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlaySlick#DatabaseConfig-via-runtime-dependency-injection)

**Update**

`sbt` won't take `-D` option if you are not running it in the interactive mode. You have two options, the easiest is to run in the interactive mode

```
RPs-MacBook-Pro:play RP$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/RP/play/project
[info] Resolving key references (11994 settings) ...
[info] Set current project to play (in build file:/Users/RP/play/)
[play] $
```

and then execute `~run "-Dconfig.file=conf/application-dev.conf"`, it should work just fine.

The other option is to export a system variable (ex: `APP_DEV_CONF_FILE`) and use it in `build.sbt`

```
val devConfigFile = sys.env.get("APP_DEV_CONF_FILE") match {
  case Some(config) => config
  case None => "application-prod"
}

javaOptions in run ++= Seq(
  "-Dconfig.file=conf/" + devConfigFile + ".conf"
)
```

With this, you can directly use `sbt run`, no need of running in interactive mode.

Comment: I tried this: `sbt "~ run 9001 -Dconfig.file=./conf/application-dev.conf"` but the different conf was ignored

Comment: can I do this on windows as well?

Comment: Yes, you can, just make sure that your `sbt\bin` in the path. And from the command prompt, go to your project home directory, where `build.sbt` is there - and do `sbt` and enter.. you will be in SBT interactive mode